# Deep copying reference types

Tags: c#, .net

I am using a class called BigNumDesc that represents a number. I have a jagged array of that numbers, that represent a matrix.
I first declare this matrix the following way:

```
    BigNumDec[][] matrix = new BigNumDec[][] {
        new BigNumDec[] { 1, 2 },
        new BigNumDec[] { 3, 4 }
    };
```

Now, I have this method I want to call:

```
static BigNumDec[][] GetStrictlyUpperTriangle(BigNumDec[][] matrix)
{
    BigNumDec[][] newMatrix = new BigNumDec[matrix.Length][];
    matrix.CopyTo(newMatrix, 0);
    return null;
}
```

I have a break-point in the last line. If in the watch window, I take any item of matrix, and change it, it will change too newMatrix, as all BigNumDec are reference types(bad design decision from the creator of it?). How can I accomplish this? I need to make modifications to newMatrix, so I must copy it first from matrix.

edit: Tried the same now with ints, but it's happening just the same. I'd it wouldn't happen with value types?

BigNumDec is immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's still happening with value types is because you're using an array of arrays. You're shallow-copying the "outer" array, which just copies the references to the two "inner" arrays.

You haven't shown whether `BigNumDec` is immutable or not (I would hope so) but if it is, you should be fine if you just deep copy the array. Alternatively, can you use a rectangular array `[,]` instead of a jagged array `[][]`? If so, a simple copy would suffice. There are performance implications with rectangular arrays, mind you - it's worth testing this to see whether it'll be a problem for you. You get better locality of reference, but the actual array access isn't as fast.

Comment: With a simple for it works well with ints. Will it work well with BigNumDec? I'd say no.

Comment: Could you explain why being immutable or not makes a difference here, if possible? When it detects I want to change the value, does it create a new one behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your initialisation of the BigNumDec array, you are creating a 1-dimensional array of BigNumDec objects. [0] = { 1, 2 }, [1] = { 3. 4 }. You are then effectively copying the references those objects, not their content, hence why the values continue to change.

Change your initialisation to:

```
BigNumDec[,] matrix = new BigNumDec[,] {
    { 1, 2 },
    { 3, 4 }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If your objects are Serializable you can implement deep copy using serialization. It's not very efficient (by performance) but it's simple.

```
public BigNumDec[][] CopyUsingSerialization(BigNumDec[][] original)
{
    var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    var serializationStream = new MemoryStream();
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(serializationStream, original);
    serializationStream.Position = 0;
    var copy = (BigNumDec[][])binaryFormatter.Deserialize(serializationStream);
    return copy;
}
```

You have to declare the *BigNumDec* as [Serializable]:

```
[Serializable]
public class BigNumDec
{
    //class content
}
```

*(as said in other answers here, if you can move to two dimensional array instead of jagged  you'll get better solution)*